# Event-study with continous treatment in R using fixest

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel dataset with "id", "year" (1970 to 2000), and "post" a dummy which takes a value=1 if year > 1985. The treatment variable ("treatment") is a continuous variable measured in 1985. A control variable ("control") is a continuous variable measured in 1985. To calculate TWFE I used the following code:

```
res = feols(dep_var ~  treatment*post + control*post  | id + year, 
            df)
summary(res)
```

Assuming I specified the TWFE correctly, to do the event study I do the following:

```
res = feols(dep_var ~  treatment*post  + 
        i(year, treatment, 1985) | id + year + control*post,  df)
summary(res)
coefplot(res, ci_level = 0.95)
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do the event study. Can someone comment on the syntax of the event study.

Comment: Welcome. To be clear, the variable `treatment` is 0 *before* 1985, then takes on positive numeric values from 1985 onward?

Comment: Yes, you are right.